# Avoid recursively fetching specific folders in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a Visual Studio solution with several projects. I clean up the bin and obj folders as part of clean up using the following script.

```
Get-ChildItem -path source -filter obj -recurse | Remove-Item -recurse
Get-ChildItem -path source -filter bin -recurse | Remove-Item -recurse
```

This works perfectly. However, I have a file-based data folder that has about 600,000 sub folders in it and is located in a folder called FILE_DATA.

The above script takes ages because it goes through all these 600,000 folders.

I need to avoid FILE_DATA folder when I recursively traverse and remove bin and obj folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the FILE_DATA folder is a subfolder of $source (not deeper), try:

```
$source = "C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\test"
Get-Item -Path $source\* -Exclude "FILE_DATA" | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | % {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter "obj" -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter "bin" -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse
}
```

Comment: The folder is a grand sub folder from source.  This works..but it still goes inside FILE_DATA folder.

Comment: grand subfolder?  ex. `$source = c:\test`  and `FILE_DATA is c:\test\FILE_DATA`?

Comment: tested it now. it didn't delete FILE_DATA when I used `$source = c:\test` but when running PS 2.0 it didn't care about `-Include` so it delete pretty much everything else :P  Fixed it now

Comment: For those who just want to delete all `bin` and `obj` folders in their solution's project folders, simply replace the first line by `Get-ChildItem -Directory | % {` (the -Directory flag is part of PowerShell 3). If you want to delete `bin` and `obj` only from immediate children, drop the `-Recurse` flag before the pipe. Also, `-Path $_.FullName` can be shortened to `$_`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more efficient approach that does what you need--skip subtrees that you want to exclude:

```
function GetFiles($path = $pwd, [string[]]$exclude)
{
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {
        if ($exclude | Where {$item -like $_}) { continue }

        $item
        if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container)
        {
            GetFiles $item.FullName $exclude
        }
    }
}
```

This code is adapted from Keith Hill's answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024103/how-to-retrieve-a-recursive-directory-and-file-list-from-powershell-excluding-so); my contribution is one bug fix and minor refactoring; you will find a complete explanation in my answer to that same SO question.

This invocation should do what you need:

```
GetFiles -path source -exclude FILE_DATA
```

For even more leisurely reading, check out my article on Simple-Talk.com that discusses this and more: [Practical PowerShell: Pruning File Trees and Extending Cmdlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024103/how-to-retrieve-a-recursive-directory-and-file-list-from-powershell-excluding-so).

Comment: This has solved my problem. I made little changes to make it work for me.  I'll post my code soon.  Thank you.

Comment: function RemoveBinAndObj($path = $pwd, [string[]]$remove, [string[]]$exclude)
    {
        foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
        {
            if ($exclude | Where {$item -like $_}) { continue }

            if ($remove | Where {$item -like $_})  
            { 
                 Write-Host "Removing " + $item.FullName
                 Remove-Item $item.FullName -Recurse 
            }

            if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container)
            {
                RemoveBinAndObj $item.FullName $remove $exclude
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry, but Graimer has a more concise and best solution.  Your solution works perfectly too.  It solves the problem.  But Graimer's solution is more concise and also executes faster.

Comment: Since you now state that you are interested just in immediate children then I agree--@Graimer's special case solution is more appropriate. My solution addresses the more general scenario of any descendants, not just immediate children.