# Powershell Recursively getting filtered list of files in directory

Tags: windows, powershell, recursion

I am trying to recursively get a list of a files in a tree, unfortunately I can't figure it out.

The Powershell function below was taken from Michael Sorens answer to [How to retrieve a recursive directory and file list from PowerShell excluding some files and folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024103/how-to-retrieve-a-recursive-directory-and-file-list-from-powershell-excluding-so)

```
function GetFiles($path = $pwd, [string[]]$exclude)
{
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {
        if ($exclude | Where {$item -like $_}) { continue }

        $item
        if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container)
        {
            GetFiles $item.FullName $exclude
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the original directory listing

> C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\1
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\1\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\1\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\1\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\1\log C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\10
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\10\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\10\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\10\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\10\log
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\11
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\11\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\11\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\11\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\11\log
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\12
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\12\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\12\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\12\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\12\log
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\13
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\13\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\13\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\13\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\27\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\27\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\27\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\27\log
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28\log
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\29

I run the function passing:

```
GetFiles "." ["*1*"]
```

I expect to get (but don't)

> C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\27\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\27\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\27\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\27\log
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28\build.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28\changelog.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28\junitResult.xml
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\28\log
>   C:\test\jobs\AJenkinJob\builds\29

I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong :(

Comment: What's up with the `[]` around your second parameter argument (`["*1*"]`)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Am I getting my scripting languages mixed up, e.g. it should be a list the second parameter?

Comment: PowerShell will automatically figure that out from the function definition, no need to worry about that :-) Also, `[]` is not the proper array/list operator in PowerShell. You would use `@()` if anything

Comment: GetFiles "." "1*" "2*" doesn't work though.... Come back Linux, all is forgiven :)

Comment: Should be `"*1*","*2*"`

Comment: Updated answer to show how you can achieve *exactly* that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I run the function passing:
>
> ```
> GetFiles "." ["*1*"]
> ```

In argument mode, the PowerShell parser will treat each individual argument to a command like an expandable string unless it's told otherwise (see below), meaning that PowerShell ends up interpreting `["*1*"]` as a string literal, and the `-like` operation inside the function behaves very differently from what you expect.

Simply drop the square brackets:

```
GetFiles . *1*
```

---

If you want to explicitly pass an array as an argument, use the array subexpression operator, `@()` (this will cause the parser to evaluate the argument as an expression and treat the output as an array, before binding it to a parameter):

```
GetFiles . @("*1*")
```

If your array needs to contain multiple values, separate by comma:

```
GetFiles . @("*1*","*2*")
```

or

```
GetFiles . *1*,*2*
```

---

Another approach would be to declare the parameters in an inline `Param()` block and use the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter attribute, this will let you supply an unbounded number of arguments to the command, much like `params` in C#:

```
function GetFiles
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        $path = $pwd, 

        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [string[]]$exclude
    )

    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {
        if ($exclude | Where {$item -like $_}) { continue }

        $item
        if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container)
        {
            GetFiles $item.FullName $exclude
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
GetFiles . *1* *2*
```

all you want