# Exclude directory from ls recursive search

Tags: powershell

I would like to list all directories named bin and obj that are anywhere in the current directory tree *but without descending into the `node_modules`* directory.

I've tried `ls . -Recurse -Include bin,obj -Exclude node_modules` but that doesn't work and still includes things inside `node_modules`.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yes except the accepted answer doesn't really answer the question does it? Lots of ways that could not match properly.

Comment: It answers that `-exclude` won't work for this use case, that the way forward is to use the pipeline and create a filter that fits your use case. It's not exactly a copy-and-paste answer for your conditions. I can only really imagine it failing completely if your current directory is already inside a `node_modules` folder, presumably you know if that is the case. Instead, this discussion is more thorough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024103/how-to-retrieve-a-recursive-directory-and-file-list-from-powershell-excluding-so

Comment: Except for the file mask, `Where-Object` is always more reliable than `Get-ChildItem -Include` and `-Exclude` options are.  I avoid both `-Include` and `-Exclude` entirely.  They're too flaky with too many caveats, and never behave like I expect.  Similarly, I avoid `-Recurse` on `Copy-Item` and `Remove-Item` in favor of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`.  Yes, it sucks.  Microsoft will fix it as soon as they fix the version numbers in the path for the PowerShell.exe.